# C# 401 error when send request to REST service

Tags: c#, rest, authorization

I am trying to send http request to request for a REST Service. However, I keep receiving 401 error. I have included a basic authorization information in http header, but it still received the same 401 error. Could anyone help me check my code plz? Thanks！

```
    public void getAuth(string reqUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqUrl);
        string userinfo = "test:test";
        byte[] byteUserInfo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userinfo);
        string code = Convert.ToBase64String(byteUserInfo);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + code);
        req.Method = "get";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tester2 test = new Tester2();
        test.getAuth("http://MyHost/wiki/rest/prototype/1/search/site?query=property");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines:

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,* /*;q=0.8";
```

Comment: Hi lgoy, thanks for the answer.  I have tried it and it returned a 400 error (bad request).  I have checked the developer manual of the relevant REST service, it mentions "Use HTTP basic authentication (Authorisation HTTP header) containing 'Basic username:password'. Please note however, username:password must be base64 encoded. The URL must also contain the 'os_authType=basic' query parameter". I think the occurence of 401 error might because I have not insert 'os_authType=basic' in my URL.  However, they have not provide further instruction of where to insert this parameter.